# How to bind to a ViewBox in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, layout, silverlight-4.0

I have used the ViewBox Silverlight Toolkit control to bind to, however Silverlight 4 add this to the Core, however it no longer has a specific "Content" property to bind to - how to I bind Content to the new ViewBox?

---

For example I want to be able to do this (not valid syntax):

```
<ViewBox Content="{Binding Path=Canvas}"/>
```

Where the Content of the  the Viewbox is a Canvas which can itself be many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I put a ContentPresenter inside the ViewBox and Bind to this it works - putting this as the answer as it may be useful so others as it solved the issue.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Canvas}"/>
```